# JQuery Auto Rotate And Pause On Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new on jquery, and Im trying to make a rotating carousel, i found a script on the internet but it doesn't include the auto rotate script and paus on hover, so here's the code :

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
  currdeg = 0;

$(".next").on("click", {
  d: "n"
}, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", {
  d: "p"
}, rotate);

function rotate(e) {
  if (e.data.d == "n") {
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if (e.data.d == "p") {
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

anyone can help me adding the code needed for auto rotating and pause on hover would be a big help..thank you :)

Comment: please try below article http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-slider-with-custom-direction-nav.html

Comment: try to apply it but still won't auto slide

Answer (score 0):

please try it...

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
         auto: true,
   autoControls: true,
   stopAutoOnClick: true,
   pager: true,
   slideWidth: 300
      });
  });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 3em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/food/1/" title="Himn yammi!"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/food/2/" title="I like food" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/food/3/" title="I like it!" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please try this using bxslider 
 [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xEM5Z/176/)

Comment: this is the full code, how to apply the auto rotate and pause on hover https://codepen.io/christyJ/pen/GOwQgX